# Understanding strpos, preg_replace, and preg_match functions

Tags: php

I'm working on a WordPress site and want to add `rel="noreferrer noopener"` to all external links. I have found a function that is doing exactly what I want, but I would like to expand it. What I want to do is if the link has `rel="nofollow"`, then replace it with `rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"`.

Here is the function I'm working on, and I have difficulties to understand several functions. I would like to understand them so I can resolve my issue.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'rel_function');

function rel_function($content) {   
    return preg_replace_callback('/<a[^>]+/', 'rel_all_external_links', $content);  
}
 
function rel_all_external_links($Matches) {
    
    $externalLink = $Matches[0];
    $SiteLink = get_bloginfo('url');
 
    if (strpos($link, 'rel') === false)   {
        $externalLink = preg_replace("%(href=\S(?!$SiteLink))%i", 'rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" $1', $externalLink);
    } elseif (preg_match("%href=\S(?!$SiteLink)%i", $externalLink)) {
        $externalLink = preg_replace('/rel=\S(?!nofollow)\S*/i', 'rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"', $externalLink);
    } 

    return $externalLink;
 
}
```

First thing I don't understand is `if (strpos($link, 'rel') === false)`. How come is that `$link` is undefined? I don't understand how `strpos` is getting value for this variable? And does this returns true if the link doesn't have `'rel'`?

The second is `$externalLink = preg_replace("%(href=\S(?!$SiteLink))%i", 'rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" $1', $externalLink);`
If I'm understanding correctly, `preg_replace` checks if `$extenalLink` doesn't contain base URL and replace all string except `href="..."`? Is that correct?

And the last one:

```
elseif (preg_match("%href=\S(?!$SiteLink)%i", $externalLink)) {
        $externalLink = preg_replace('/rel=\S(?!nofollow)\S*/i', 'rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"', $externalLink);
    }
```

It checks if `$externalLink` doesn't have a base URL, right? I'm not sure what `preg_replace` is trying to do here, but I think it is the key to my problem.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is this your code or is this someone else's code you're just trying to analyze?

Answer (score 0):

`strpos` is a function that allows you to find if a specific word or combination of characters present in the string you provided. It's like yes/no and additionally, it can give you it's start location. It is important to note that it will return false when nothing is found or a number, including 0 when the match is found.

So this function is very good for simple scenarios like does it have letters `app` in the word `apple`? the answer is yes, and the start position is 0.

In the example, you provided `if (strpos($link, 'rel') === false)` it searches if word rel is present, and it doesn't matter in what position.

`preg_match` is used for much complex searching using regex, capable of searching multiple conditions, groups and more. To give an example of what it can search: the word `apprehensive` does it starts with `app` and ends with `sive`? - answer yes. If `strpos` would've been used, it would say yes to all such cases due to the `app` being present but the ending is never checked as it's incapable of such thing. `preg_match` can commonly be used to get what's inside of an attribute, so it grabs rel="[what's here]".

`Preg_replace` is replacing something using regex for complex searching first, then do the replacement of a match.

I would always advise to read up documentation provided by php for the functions and it's accepted arguments.

[Information about strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

[Information about preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace)

[Information about preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match)

[Information about regex (takes a good while to learn!)](https://regexr.com/)